# Query how many times target date changed in TFS

Tags: tfs

We're using TFS for our daily team stand ups which are more task driven vs development iterations.  We'd like to be able to track how many times a target date changed & in what areas that's happening the most to see if we can pinpoint bottlnecks.  I'm having a heck of a time figuring out a query that will give me these results.  I tried querying "History Contains Words changed target date" (based off the image you'll see in the link below) but got no results.  When I just say "history contains words date", it only gives me results where someone said the word "date" in a discussion field.

Any ideas?
[Screenshot of History Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmGN7.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's an expected behavior. Comments entered into the Discussion area are queryable. Change history entries, such as which fields were changed, aren't queryable.

Check the following link for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/queries/history-and-auditing?view=vsts&tabs=browser